# Dúvida em relação ao === e !=

Tags: php

Estou com uma dúvida em mostrar dados apenas se estiverem preenchidos.
Já utilizei o `===` e o `!=`, mas com nenhum deles está a funcionar.

```
 <p>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Nome1"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["DataNascimento"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7">' .(date('Y/m/d') - $exibe["DataNascimento"] ).'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Funcao1"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["EPISValidade"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["MedicaValidade"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> <a href="TrabalhadorMostrar1.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'"> Ver Documentos </a></div>
 </div>


    ';
        if ($exibe['Nome1'] === '') {

 }

    '<p>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Nome1"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["DataNascimento"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7">' .(date('Y/m/d') - $exibe["DataNascimento"] ).'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Funcao1"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["EPISValidade"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["MedicaValidade"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> <a href="TrabalhadorMostrar1.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'"> Ver Documentos </a></div>
 </div>';
```

/////

```
        if($exibe['Nome3'] != NULL) {
        '<p>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Nome1"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["DataNascimento"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7">' .(date('Y/m/d') - $exibe["DataNascimento"] ).'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["Funcao1"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["EPISValidade"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> '.$exibe["MedicaValidade"].'</div>
 <div class="columna7"> <a href="TrabalhadorMostrar1.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'"> Ver Documentos </a></div>
  </div>';}
```

O Primeiro mostra. Os outros dois existem e não me mostra os dados.

Comment: `===` Compara o `tipo` de dado(string, integer etc) e o `valor`, já `!=` verifica apenas se o valor é diferente. [operadores](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use o método `is_null()`

```
 if (is_null($exibe['Nome1'])) { //...
```

Comment: Essa situação é idêntica ao do primeiro correcto? 
 if (empty($exibe['Nome1'])) { //Aqui não mostra nada

Comment: Veja agora pois dará certo

Comment: Seria uma boa deixar a resposta mais completa para a pergunta: "Duvida em relação ao === e !=", explicar o motivo de ter usado o is_null, pois apenas jogou uma resposta, mas o não explicou a diferença e o porque do === não ter dado certo.

Comment: E por isso dá um negativo? Valeu!

Answer (score 3):

Verifique a documentação do PHP: [operadores](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php)

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php) verifica se uma variável esta vazia

[isset()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) verifica se uma ou mais variável(eis) (ou índice(s) de array) foi(ram) criada(o)(s) E se possui valor diferente de NULL @Bruno Augusto

Comment: isset() verifica se uma **ou mais** variável(eis) (ou índice(s) de array) foi(ram) criada(o)(s) **E** se possui valor diferente de NULL.

Answer (score 3):

Quando você usa o operador **===** (ou sua contraparte **!==**) você está dizendo para o programa comparar o lado esquerdo com o direito não apenas em valor mas também em tipo.

De forma bem didática se você tiver dois valores `0` e `'0'`, isto é, um inteiro zero e uma string numérica, você só poderia distingui-los com esse tipo de operador pois ambos representam a mesma coisa, mas são de tipos de diferentes.

Já seus irmãos menores, **==** e **!=** comparam apenas o valor. Veja um exemplo:

```
$a = 0;
$b = '0';

var_dump( $a == $b, $a === $b );
```

A saída desse programa é:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

O primeiro TRUE porque **$a** tem o mesmo valor de **$b**. Já o segundo retorna FALSE porque um é um *integer* e o outro uma *string*.

No seu caso em particular só seria possível afirmar com 100% de certeza se soubéssemos o que ou como foi definido o array **$exibe**, porém, mesmo sem conhecê-los é possível sugerir que seja feita a comparação não apenas com operadores, mas sim com as funções [isset()](http://www.php.net/isset) e [empty()](http://www.php.net/empty):

```
if ( isset( $exibe['Nome1'] ) && ! empty( $exibe['Nome1'] ) ) {}
```