# Valores nulos no PHP

Tags: php, null

No PHP 7 qual é correta forma de se definir e identificar valores nulos?

Qual dessas é forma correta para atribuir nulo?

```
$valor = null;

$valor = "";
```

Qual dessas é forma correta para identificar valores nulos?

```
if($valor == null){}

if($valor == "") {}

if($valor === null) {}
```

Comment: [Sinal idêntico “===” é usado apenas em PHP? Por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186885/91) e [Dúvida em relação ao === e !=](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26159/91)

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73007/qual-o-mais-r%C3%A1pido-is-nully-ou-y-null

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Veja na própria [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php).

Isto é um nulo:

```
$valor = null;
```

Isto é uma *string* vazia, nada de nulo:

```
$valor = "";
```

Assim compara nulo, só que uma *string* vazia é considerada nula também, é um completo *non-sense*, mas o PHP é assim:

```
if ($valor == null) {}
```

Isto verifica se é uma *string* vazia:

```
if ($valor == "") {}
```

Costuma-se considerar uma forma melhor de comprar, mas neste caso não faz diferença real:

```
if ($valor === null) {}
```

Também pode fazer:

```
if (is_null($valor)) {}
```

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php).

Ou:

```
if (empty($valor)) {}
```

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Vai encontrar diferença em casos assim:

```
$a = array();
echo $a == null; //true
echo $a === null;  //false
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Typing/Null.php).

É tão confuso, que eu evitaria o uso de nulos em PHP.

|  | empty() / ==null | is_null() / ===null | isset() | array_key_exists() |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ϕ | T | T | F | F |
| null | T | T | F | T |
| "" | T | F | T | T |
| [] | T | F | T | T |
| 0 | T | F | T | T |
| false | T | F | T | T |
| true | F | F | T | T |
| 1 | F | F | T | T |
| \0 | F | F | T | T |

Tabela retirada de [resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15607549/221800).

Pelo menos em linguagens "normais" é assim:

[image: NULL != 0]

Comment: Sei que não pode comentar aqui atoa, mas gostei dessa foto do exemplo kkkkkkkk

Comment: @LeandroSilvaCampos não é tão rígido assim não.

Comment: Ilustração show. kkkkk

Answer (score 2):

Para definir é com [null](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) e para verificar é com [is_null($valor);](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-null.php) que retorna [um valor verdadeiro ou falso (boleano) se é ou não NULL](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-null.php) não indicaria as outras formas que até funcionam, mas, que de vez em quando trazem resultados inesperados, então, verifique sempre com a função responsável para isso, ***exemplo:***

***Código:***

```
<?php

    $valor = null;    
    var_dump(is_null($valor));
    echo PHP_EOL;
    var_dump(($valor) == null);
    echo PHP_EOL;
    var_dump(($valor) === null);
    echo PHP_EOL;
```

***Saída:***

```
bool(true)

bool(true)

bool(true)
```

deu a mesma resposta.

[***Exemplo ONLINE***](https://ideone.com/EsaNi3)

As aspas simples ou duplas sem espaço significam `string` vazia e deve ser verificada com [empty($valor)](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php), exemplo:

***Código:***

```
<?php

    $valor = "";

    var_dump(empty($valor));
    echo PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($valor=="");
    echo PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($valor==="");
    echo PHP_EOL;
```

***Saída:***

```
bool(true)

bool(true)

bool(true)
```

que também deu a mesma resposta, ou seja, vai funcionar as 3 maneiras exibidas, mas, utilize sempre se existir na linguagem suas funções responsáveis para isso.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que melhor forma seja com `false`, pois não tem restrição de tipos

```
$valor = [0, null, false, ''];

foreach($valor as $v){
  if($v == false) echo 'null';
}

/*
Resultado 

null
null
null
null

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você usar "" isso não é nulo e sim uma string vazia.

Utilize este comando que pega o tipo da variável para você entender melhor:

```
echo gettype("");
echo gettype(null);
```

O primeiro vai retornar string e o segundo nulo

Enquanto a comparação quando você usa == você compara somente o valor por exemplo:

```
if("2" == 2)
```

Isso vai retornar verdadeiro já que os dois são o valor dois.

mas se você utiliza:

```
if("2" === 2)
```

Vai ser falso já que os valores são dois, mas um é uma string e o outro é um valor numérico, ou seja === compara o valor e também o tipo da variável.