# Como posso diferenciar uma string 'NULL' de um valor de fato nulo?

Tags: php, mysql, query

Fiz este exemplo para vocês entenderem como esta sendo feita a consulta no banco no meu sistema.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["campo"];
    }
}
```

Meu problema é o seguinte, estou pegando o resultado da consulta e seto ela em um objeto, até ai tudo bem, o problema é quando chegam valores nulos, se eu tiver uma string 'NULL' ou um campo nulo o resultado é o mesmo, como posso diferencia nulo de uma string 'NULL'?

Valores no objeto:

```
   'nChegada' => 'NULL',
   'nExpedido' => 'NULL',
```

Um esta com o valor nulo e o outro com uma string 'NULL'.

**UPDATE**

Valor de n_chegada e n_estado são nulos e de n_expedido é uma string

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
public function getDadoById($id) {
    $stmt = $this->conexao->getQuery("select * from " . $this->getTabela() . " WHERE `id` = " . $id);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $cla = null;
    if (count($results) > 0) {
        $atributos = $this->getAtributos();
        $classe = 'model\dominio\\' . ucfirst($this->getTabela());
        $cla = new $classe();
        foreach ($atributos as $atributo) {
            $metodo = 'set' . ucfirst($atributo);
            if(is_null($results[0][$this->atributoToDb($atributo)])){
                $cla->$metodo(NULL);
            }else{
                $cla->$metodo($results[0][$this->atributoToDb($atributo)]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $cla;
}
```

Tentei com o exemplo do Roberto de Campos, mas o resultado foi o mesmo:

```
model\dominio\Funcionario::__set_state(array(
   'id' => '1',
   'pis' => '12345678901',
   'numeroCarteira' => '12345',
   'serie' => '1234',
   'nome' => 'Trabalhador Padrão',
   'mae' => 'Mãe do Trabalhador Padrão',
   'pai' => 'Pai do Trabalhador Padrão',
   'dataNascimento' => '10/10/1988',
   'sexo' => '1',
   'estadoCivil' => '1',
   'naturalidade' => '2680',
   'rg' => '1234567890',
   'cpf' => '12345678901',
   'cnh' => '12345678901',
   'tituloEleitoral' => '123456789012',
   'secao' => '1234',
   'zona' => '123',
   'localEmissao' => '2680',
   'nacionalidade' => '7',
   'nChegada' => 'NULL',
   'nExpedido' => 'NULL',
   'nEstado' => 'NULL',
   'observacao' => 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.',
   'email' => 'trabalhor@padrao.com',
   'senha' => '123',
   'dataEmissao' => '2017-10-23 13:12:42',
))
```

Comment: O resultado não é o mesmo, um campo do tipo texto com o conteúdo NULL retorna NULL, agora se o campo for NULL (não tiver valor) será retornado vazio.

Comment: Mas se eu pego $row["campo"] e jogo no meu objeto como o mysql retorna null, ele entende da mesma forma de uma string 'null'.

Comment: Esse ponto que você não esta entendendo, o `MySQL` não retorna `NULL` ele retorna vazio. O que você pode fazer é verificar se a coluna tem algum dado.

Comment: "não retorna NULL", mas ele retornou null

Comment: Verifica minha resposta que você vai entende o que eu estou falando. Quem esta escrevendo `NULL` na tela é o `PHP` e não o `MySQL`. O `PHP` escreve `NULL` quando você `printa` um campo sem informação nenhuma

Comment: [Valores nulos no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/238961/91)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `MySQL` não retorna uma `string` com o conteúdo `NULL` quando o campo é nulo, ele retorna uma coluna sem dado nenhum, então você pode verificar se o retorno tem dado ou não com a função `is_null`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if (is_null($row["campo"]))
            echo "Este campo não tem dado nenhum";
        else
            echo "Este campo tem o seguinte conteúdo: ".$row["campo"];
    }
}
```

Outra forma de você verificar esse retorno `NULL` é usando o comparativo `=== NULL`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["campo"] === null)
            echo "Este campo não tem dado nenhum";
        else
            echo "Este campo tem o seguinte conteúdo: ".$row["campo"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Não é bem "uma coluna sem dado nenhum" que ele retorna, é uma coluna com o valor `null` do PHP.

Comment: @bfavaretto ia comentar o mesmo. De qq forma, apesar do erro de terminologia, a solução é correta.

Comment: Amigo, editei a pergunta tentando a forma que você fez, mas o resultado foi o mesmo

Comment: @WictorChaves sugiro ler com atenção a resposta e todos os comentários feitos. O problema está na premissa errada da pergunta. O valor retornado ao PHP é nulo, e não uma string. O seu problema está na maneira que exibe na tela. Ao usar o valor em PHP, o is_null funciona sem problemas. Se o que quer é exibir outra coisa, use `SELECT COALESCE( coluna, '---' ) AS sem_nulo` ou algo do tipo. Se quiser simplesmente exibir vazio, basta a solução do Roberto. Verifique ainda se não está utilizando algo extra na classe usada para ler o DB, que esteja interferindo com a leitura.

Comment: Verdade, deu um var_dump e vi que são diferentes, confundi por causa do ''.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode filtrar os nulos na própria seleção do mysql, assim:

```
SELECT ProductID, Name, Color
FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product
WHERE Color IS NULL
```

E caso o color fosse um valor texto seria assim:

```
SELECT ProductID, Name, Color
FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product
WHERE Color = 'NULL'
```

Estes campos são tratados de forma diferente, pelo banco.

Comment: Isso é no filtro, nas eu creio que o AP deseja diferenciar no resgate. +1 de qualquer sorte

Comment: Obrigado, mas eu preciso saber no retorno como o @JeffersonQuesado falou.

Comment: Entendi, vou ver aqui

Comment: @WictorChaves o que o roberto respondeu ta certo ne?